# Object within another object, require them to modify values used elsewhere

Tags: java

I have currently created a new CountDownTimer object in my java file, I then have that timer have an onFinish() method where it makes another new CountDownTimer object that has required functionality in it's own onFinish() method.

However when I create a boolean value outside of the second timer (and maintain it as false) and then attempt to modify this boolean to true within the onFinish() method of the second timer it gives me the error:"Variable [boolean variable name] is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final".

When I declare the variable final though I absolutely cannot modify it.

So what is the most effective way to go about resolving this problem? I cannot lose the functionality of the timers, yet my experience with java is very shallow. I apologise if this question seems silly.

I would love to also use something like a getter/setter method but with a timer I am not sure if that would even be effective.

Thank you to everyone who replies in advance! It is greatly appreciated! :)

For the sake of clarity: I require the timer to set a boolean flag that will detect that the second timer has indeed finished. This will set the boolean flag to true and then with that I modify the functionality of a button I created. In a similar fashion I also desire this second timer to initialize a long value to be referenced outside of it as well.

If the boolean = false then the button causes a rejection of the user.
If the boolean = true then the button accepts the user.
And then I use the long number obtained below.

Code as requested:

```
boolean clickAppropriate = false;

new CountDownTimer(t1, t2) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("text");

        new CountDownTimer(t3, t4) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            public void onFinish() {
                long startTime = System.nanoTime();

                clickAppropriate = true;
            }
        }.start();

    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Show code relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix I see here without modifying the structure of your solution is to choose ´final boolean[] clickAppropriate = new boolean[1]´ and work with ´clickAppropriate[0]´ element instead. Choosing AtomicBoolean might give extra benefit if you work with multiple threaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `this` keyword together with the outer class (The class where the boolean is declared) name to access its member.

Example:

```
public class Outer {
    public boolean bool = false;
    public class Inner {
        public void displayOuterClassVariable () {
            System.out.println(Outer.this.bool);
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you need to use your outer class name with `clickApprpriate`. But it seems like your variable is declared in a method. You have to put that variable in the class in order to use this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. The way that you have your code currently structured, you will not be able to alter the contents of your `clickAppropriate` variable from within your anonymous `CountDownTimer` class declaration.

This is what Oracle writes in regards to accessing local variables from within Anonymous Classes:

"An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as `final` or effectively final."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

This is the reason why your compiler is giving you this error.

One way that you can access and alter your `clickApproriate` variable from within your anonymous class is to change this variable from being a local variable to being a class variable.

I was able to successfully compile the below code without any errors.

```
public class Main 
{
    static boolean clickAppropriate;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
        clickAppropriate = false;        

        new CountDownTimer()
        {                    
            public void onFinish()
            {                  
                clickAppropriate = true;
            };

        }.start();
    }
}
```

One thing that I would point out that is not evident - your use of anonymous classes is in affect overriding any code declared in your class file. For example, each time you declare your anonymous class `CountDownTimer` as follows:

```
new CountDownTimer(t1, t2) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
};
```

This is overriding any code in the `onTick()` method that might be present in the `CountDownTimer` class file. This is correct when the `onTick()` method is abstract, but might not be what you had intended if this method is a regular class method. Best of luck.